# How can I add favorites in Kubuntu Network Release Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, kubuntu, knr

Since the upgrade of my netbook from lucid KNR to maverick KNR, it is not possible anymore to add to the favourites on the search and launch site. The "stars" to add an icon to the favourites is not shown anymore, neither is the "-"-sign on the favourites to remove them.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the cashew in the bottom left.  Click "Unlock Page".  Do what you want.

Comment: I click on it, but nothing happens

Comment: There is a bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=233234 that prevents the page to be unlocked if the widgets are locked. After  unlocking both, I am able to add or delete favourites.

Answer (score 0):

If you shutdown from the console (sudo shutdown -h now or sudo shudown -r ) or you just power off the netbook without shutting down, none of the customizations will be saved.  Make sure you do a shutdown command to save everything

Jonathan